# form_for not calling specified action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, form-for

I have a Party model in a Rails app, and need to update it via a form. In my Party show view (show.html.erb), I have a form that begins with:

```
  <%= form_for @party, :url => {:action => "update" } do |f|%>
```

and in my Parties controller, I have:

```
def update
 @party = Party.find(party_params[:id])
 if @party.update(party_params)
   redirect_to 'show'
 else
  render '_rsvp'
end
end
```

However, this method isn't getting called. I've been looking at this forever--what am I missing?!

Comment: try this: `<%= form_for @party, :url => {:action => "update"}, method: :put do |f|%>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the `url` when using `form_for` helper as `rails` uses `@party.new_record?` to figure out whether to post to `/parties` or `/parties/:id`. The following should work for both `create` and `update` actions provided you set `@party` appropriately in the actions which render the forms.

```
<%= form_for @party do |f|%>
  <!-- fields -->
<% end %>
```

I recommend reading the docs for `form_for` helper which explains this with an example.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html